# how to Call server side method in asp.net without using static method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have HTML button in my aspx page and i want call server side method on button click then how to i achieve it.
I tried __toDoPostBack() function in JavaScript but it not calling function. and also sometime i got error _toDoPostBack()  is undefined function.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
<a href="#" onServerClick="Anchor_Click"  runat="server">Click!</a>
```

to solved my problem.

because i am writing HTML tags on Literal so that it not render.

e.g when i am try this